# Manipulate list of json into list of json using JOLT

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have an input json list as below:

```
[
  {
    "key_id": "1111",
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": true,
    "key_3": {
      "key_3_1": "value_3_1",
      "key_3_2": "value_3_2"
    }
  },
  {
    "key_id": "2222",
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": true,
    "key_3": {
      "key_3_1": "value_3_1",
      "key_3_2": "value_3_2"
    }
  }
]
```

I need this list to be transformed as below:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1111",               // Extract from key_id
    "data": {                   // complete json goes here within 'data'
      "key_id": "1111",
      "key_1": "value_1",
      "key_2": true,
      "key_3": {
        "key_3_1": "value_3_1",
        "key_3_2": "value_3_2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2222",
    "data": {
      "key_id": "2222",
      "key_1": "value_1",
      "key_2": true,
      "key_3": {
        "key_3_1": "value_3_1",
        "key_3_2": "value_3_2"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Each json inside list should be transformed into another json with *id* and *data* fields. *data* field should have entire json and *id* should be *key_id*.

Answer (score 1):

This spec should give you the expected output:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key_id": "[&1].id",
        "@": "[&1].data"
      }
    }
  }
]
```